# Git aliases with conditions to apply

Tags: git

I've created a simple alias which will do a push to origin and then will checkout dev branch

this is it

```
origin-push = !git push origin && git checkout develop
```

I would like to add a check to only execute if on branch master, otherwise just display a simple message. How to do that ?

--Windows user--

Comment: a bash function in your .bashrc (if bash available in your context of course)? Note about Windows : if you use Git for Windows, it includes bash capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What comes after the '!' is a shell script. You can add whatever you feel like in this command line.
- One way to view the name of your current branch is : `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

So something like :

```
! [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" = "master" ] && ...
```

should work

full command  (thx @phd) :

```
origin-push-master = ![ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" = "master ] &&
    git push origin && git checkout develop ||
        echo The current branch is not master >&2
```

---

If this action becomes too elaborate to be a simple one-liner, an alternative to a simple alias is :

create a script, named `git-origin-push`, which should be accessible from your `$PATH`.

Comment: Let me write this in full: `origin-push-master = ![ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" = "master ] && git push origin && git checkout develop || echo The current branch is not master >&2`

Comment: @MCR : indeed, there was a missing `"`. fixed